# Device /dev/sda4 not found error seen when creating physical volume

Tags: centos, fdisk

I m trying to expand my current disk but when I do `pvcreate` with the latest partition it says not found below are the command details.

One thing I noticed is the Disk label type changes to GPT from DOS after the partition I'm not sure what that means

```
login as: root
root@10.10.222.14's password:
Last login: Wed Oct 11 01:03:01 2017 from 10.10.222.122
[root@dpnjsv2-centos7-base ~]# fdisk /dev/sda
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (1 primary, 0 extended, 3 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (2-4, default 2): 4
First sector (41943040-73400319, default 41943040):
Using default value 41943040
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (41943040-73400319, default 73400319):
Using default value 73400319
Partition 4 of type Linux and of size 15 GiB is set




Command (m for help): t


Partition number (1,4, default 4): 4


Hex code (type L to list all codes): 8e


Changed type of partition 'Linux' to 'Linux LVM'

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 37.6 GB, 37580963840 bytes, 73400320 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1    41943039    20971519+  ee  GPT
/dev/sda4        41943040    73400319    15728640   8e  Linux LVM


Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
Syncing disks.
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root


[root@dpnjsv2-centos7-base ~]# partprobe


[root@dpnjsv2-centos7-base ~]# pvcreate /dev/sda4
  **Device /dev/sda4 not found (or ignored by filtering).**
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
[root@dpnjsv2-centos7-base ~]# fdisk /dev/sda
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 37.6 GB, 37580963840 bytes, 73400320 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: gpt


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       411647    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 2       411648      1435647    500M  Microsoft basic
 3      1435648     41940991   19.3G  Linux LVM

Command (m for help): pvcreate 1

Disk /dev/sda: 37.6 GB, 37580963840 bytes, 73400320 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: gpt


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       411647    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 2       411648      1435647    500M  Microsoft basic
 3      1435648     41940991   19.3G  Linux LVM
```

Answer (score 1):

The output, you've posted, looks a bit inconsistent. First you created the /dev/sda4 partition, however later it isn't listed. Does it really exist?

If yes, the most probably you have some rubbish in the begining of the /dev/sda4 partition and pvcreate isn't able to accept it. Try to clean up the the first few megabytes like:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda4 bs=1M count=20
```

We've had the similar situation recently, we've just tried to use complete /dev/sdb disk for new VG.

---

And you have created the sda4, despite you don't have sda2/3 yet:

```
Partition type:
   p   primary (1 primary, 0 extended, 3 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (2-4, default 2): 4
```

This really looks like 2 different nodes with the same name.

Comment: Exactly when i try to check it the new partition is not listed on thing to notice is that the Disk Label type also changes from dos to gpt. When i do the fdisk and print i can see Disk label type: dos. And after partition i check it Disk label type: gpt

When you mean clean up the first few megabytes what are you expectings me to do

Comment: The GPT is required by UEFI.

Comment: Ok so what is the workaround. I need to get this done some how

Comment: Is it possible you've been actually working on 2 different nodes appearing under the same name? That would explain different output of the fdisk.

Comment: No i have only one node

Comment: `Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 37.6 GB, 37580963840 bytes, 73400320 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1    41943039    20971519+  ee  GPT
/dev/sda4        41943040    73400319    15728640   8e  Linux LVM` t. I dont think creating 4 instead of default has anything to do with this

Comment: I see you have an EFI System Partition, which suggests this disk is going to be used on a UEFI system. In this case the disk label type should really be GPT, not DOS. Is it possible that the disk was partitioned to GPT before you ran fdisk on it? Maybe fdisk got confused? If possible, use gdisk instead of fdisk when using GPT partitioning.